# How do I position the interface on top?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, plantuml

How do I position the interface on top?

**1.** How to position the interface **ICreditCard** on top of **MoneyBack**?
**2.** How to position the interface **ICreditCard** on top in the middle between above **MoneyBack** and **Program**?

**3.** How to position the interface **ICreditCard** correctly on top: should it be on top or on the bottom?

**4.** Did I make the diagnosis correctly?

I want the **Program** and **MoneyBack** classes to be on the same line, and

---

**Current result**
[image]

---

## Markup

```
title Class Diagram

' === ===
left to right direction
skinparam linetype ortho
' === ===

together {
    class Program {
    + Main(args: string[]): void
    }

    class MoneyBack {
    + GetCardType(): string
    + GetCreditLimit(): int
    + GetAnnualCharge(): int
    }
}

interface ICreditCard {
  + GetCardType(): string
  + GetCreditLimit(): int
  + GetAnnualCharge(): int
}

' === ===
Program -up-> ICreditCard
Program ..> MoneyBack
ICreditCard <|-up- MoneyBack
```

---

## Code

**Program**

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        ICreditCard creditCard;
        
        creditCard = new MoneyBack()
    }
}
```

**ICreditCard**

```cs
public interface ICreditCard
{
    string GetCardType();
    int GetCreditLimit();
    int GetAnnualCharge();
}
```

**MoneyBack**

```cs
public class MoneyBack : ICreditCard
{
    public string GetCardType()
    {
        return "MoneyBack";
    }
    public int GetCreditLimit()
    {
        return 15000;
    }
    public int GetAnnualCharge()
    {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

## Update 1

How do I make the **Program** and **MoneyBack** classes aligned at the top?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not using the left to right syntax and reorganizing the references to:

```
@startuml
title Class Diagram

' === ===

skinparam linetype ortho
' === ===

together {
    class Program {
    + Main(args: string[]): void
    }

    class MoneyBack {
    + GetCardType(): string
    + GetCreditLimit(): int
    + GetAnnualCharge(): int
    }
}

interface ICreditCard {
  + GetCardType(): string
  + GetCreditLimit(): int
  + GetAnnualCharge(): int
}

' === ===
ICreditCard <-down- Program 
ICreditCard <|-down- MoneyBack
Program .right.> MoneyBack

@enduml
```

which gives:

[image]

**Update 1**: plantuml does not provide a feature for aligning  classes at their top, but [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067064/1657886) explains a workaround.

Comment: How do I make the **Program** and **MoneyBack** classes aligned at the top? See **Update 1**

Comment: See **Update 1**

Comment: No direct idea but as a workaround see: stackoverflow.com/a/66067064/1657886 (note: part __ is necessary, but not the part {method})

Comment: **1.** Could you clarify if such a diagram is correct for such code?
**2.** Are the classes placed correctly on the diagram?

Comment: @eusataf Did you try to extend the example by means of the workaround indicated? When I tested it locally it all looked OK to me.

Comment: With my question, I wanted to ask: did I make the diagram correctly for such a code?

Comment: @eusataf So actually the question is no regarding my answer but more on your own question. I think that in principle this is off topic here and should be asked at the siste site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (to be honest I don't know the answer)